# composing a dateframe with an index of a datetime

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have two lists but one is a datetime. How can I combine to form a date frame with index of this datetime and the values of lista2?

```
lista1 = [datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 13, 0, 0)]
lista2 = [31488, 14335, 89]
```

Comment: I have tried pivot already

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `index` parameter from the constructor to specify a list as indices, and use the other one as data:

```
pd.DataFrame(lista2,index=lista1)
```

For your sample data, this gives:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(lista2,index=lista1)
                0
2017-11-11  31488
2017-11-12  14335
2017-11-13     89
```

Answer (score 2):

past two `list` to a `list` of `tuple`

```
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lista1,lista2))).set_index(0)
Out[646]: 
                1
0                
2017-11-11  31488
2017-11-12  14335
2017-11-13     89
```